# Get MAX value of a BIT column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SELECT request with 'inner join' in the joined table is a column with bit type.

I want to select 1 if in the joined table is at most one value with 1. If it is not the case the value will be 0.

So If I have:

```
PERSID | NAME
1      |  Toto
2      |  Titi
3      |  Tata
```

And the second table

```
PERSID | BOOL
1      |  0
1      |  0
2      |  0
2      |  1
```

I would like to have for result

```
Toto -> 0
Titi -> 1
Tata -> 0
```

I try this:

```
SELECT 
     sur.*
    ,MAX(bo.BOOL)    

    FROM SURNAME sur              
    INNER JOIN BOOL bo
    ON bo.IDPERS = sur.IDPERS
```

But MAX is not available on BIT column.. So how can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like you need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` if you want to ensure that _exactly_ one value is 1.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

you can cast it to an `INT`, and even cast it back to a `BIT` if you need to

```
SELECT 
     sur.*
    ,CAST(MAX(CAST(bo.BOOL as INT)) AS BIT)
    FROM SURNAME sur              
    INNER JOIN BOOL bo
    ON bo.IDPERS = sur.IDPERS
```

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```
max(cast(bo.BOOL as int))
```

Comment: He's just casting it as an integer so he can use the max aggregate function.

Comment: This one is much better. It also works with OVER clause.

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid the messy looking double cast by forcing an implicit cast:

```
SELECT 
     sur.*
    ,CAST(MAX(1 * bo.BOOL) AS BIT)
    FROM SURNAME sur              
    INNER JOIN BOOL bo
    ON bo.IDPERS = sur.IDPERS
```

Comment: To me, this is messier, but +1 for showing a new way of doing it I haven't seen before

Answer (score 7):

One way

```
SELECT 
     sur.*
    ,MAX(convert(tinyint,bo.BOOL))    

    FROM SURNAME sur              
    INNER JOIN BOOL bo
    ON bo.IDPERS = sur.IDPERS
```

Comment: No they are the same, I just like convert better

Answer (score 1):

If you want only those people with *exactly* one set bit:

```
declare @Surname as Table ( PersId Int, Name VarChar(10) )
insert into @Surname ( PersId, Name ) values
  ( 1, 'Toto' ), ( 2, 'Titi' ), ( 3, 'Tata' ), ( 4, 'Tutu' )

declare @Bool as Table ( PersId Int, Bool Bit )
insert into @Bool ( PersId, Bool ) values
  ( 1, 0 ), ( 1, 0 ),
  ( 2, 0 ), ( 2, 1 ),
  ( 4, 1 ), ( 4, 0 ), ( 4, 1 )

select Sur.PersId, Sur.Name, Sum( Cast( Bo.Bool as Int ) ) as [Sum],
  case Sum( Cast( Bo.Bool as Int ) )
    when 1 then 1
    else 0
    end as [Only One]
  from @Surname as Sur left outer join
    @Bool as Bo on Bo.PersId = Sur.PersId
  group by Sur.PersId, Sur.Name
  order by Sur.Name
```